# NameError: (I could run this code earlier but not anymore, probably some update?)

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **NameError: name 'startnum' is not defined**

I was using this code earlier. But now it is giving error.

```
  import sys
  if(len(sys.argv) == 1):
      print "\n\tUsage: ./%s [input PDB file] [optional: starting number 
  (default=1)] > outputfile.pdb\n" % sys.argv[0]
   quit()

  pdbfile = sys.argv[1]
  if len(sys.argv) == 2:
          startnum = 1
  if len(sys.argv) == 3:
          startnum  = int(sys.argv[2])


  pdbcode = pdbfile[-8:-4]
  with open(pdbfile, 'r') as filehandle:
       pdblines = filehandle.readlines()

  c=startnum
  for line in pdblines:

       if line[0:6] == 'REMARK':
               print line,
       if line[0:5] == 'TITLE':
               print line,
       if line[0:5] == 'MODEL':
               print line,


       if line[0:4] == 'ATOM' or line[0:6] == 'HETATM':
               part1 = line[0:12]
               resnum = line[12:16]    
               part2 = line[16:80]
               resnum = resnum.replace(' ','')
               c = c + 1
               resnum = resnum + str(c)
               finalnum = format(resnum, '4s')                 
               print part1+finalnum+part2


       if line[0:6] == 'CONECT':
               print line,
  print "END"
```

python above_code.py *.pdb

it should number atoms in all the pdb files

INPUT

```
  HETATM    1  C   UNK     0      -2.824  -0.100   0.541  1.00  0.00           C
  HETATM    2  C   UNK     0      -1.543  -0.657   0.530  1.00  0.00           C
  HETATM    3  C   UNK     0      -1.316  -1.903  -0.067  1.00  0.00           C
```

OUTPUT

```
  HETATM    1 C1   UNK     0      -2.824  -0.100   0.541  1.00  0.00           C
  HETATM    2 C2   UNK     0      -1.543  -0.657   0.530  1.00  0.00           C
  HETATM    3 C3   UNK     0      -1.316  -1.903  -0.067  1.00  0.00           C
```

So running this code will add the numbers after atom symbol in all the files end with .pdb

Comment: Look at your if conditions for the length of `sys.argv`: if there are, say, 3 *.pdf files or more, none of them pass, and `startnum` will not be set, not even be defined, hence your error.

Comment: So the error is not about an update, it's about how many arguments you use it with. Or rather, the logic to test for the number of arguments. You would be better off using something like the `argparse` module in the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you give only one sys argument the first if condition is true and startnum is not initialized
Hence when you try to do `c=startnum` it doesnt work since startnum was never initialized or defined hence the error `NameError: name 'startnum' is not defined`.

Explicitly set a default value to startnum to ensure your code works

Comment: That's not entirely correct (as in, complete): in case of too many arguments, the same problem happens.